# Bring girlfriend to Germany

Tags: visa, germany, resident-permit, family

I'm Mexican. I have a student visa for Germany. I'm allowed to work and I'm doing Studienkolleg now in order to enter university. I want to bring my girlfriend to Germany. She isn't an EU citizen either. She actually speakd good German. She has already been here. What do I need to bring her to Germany?

Comment: From my understanding, she either needs to move to Germany on her own (i.e., find a job, study place etc.), or you can marry her and bring her as your wife.